# Generating Enums directly from DB

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two tables

```
EnumType(EnumTypeID,Name,Description)

EnumTypeValue(EnumTypeValueId,Name,Value,EnumTypeID)
```

EnumTypeValue references EnumType.

General Idea is something like I want to Create Enums for all Values in EnumType
table and for each Enum its values will be corresponding values in EnumTypeValue table. Suppose I have row in EnumType(1,Gender,some description) and corresponding to it in EnumTypeValue i have two rows (1) 1,Male,5,1 (2)2,Female,6,1 .I want to create dynamically, public enum Gender {Male = 5,Female=6} so that i could use it in code as enum. There are going to be many such enums as the project will progress. All I want, just run particular code and all the enums will be generated.

I am using EntityFramework for DB interaction.Any help will be highly APPERICIATED.

Answer (score 3):

You'll probably end up having to write some T4 to generate them. Check out:

[T4 template to Generate Enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395000/t4-template-to-generate-enums)