# Generate Enum from Lookup Tables - EF 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-database-first, database-first

This might sound repeated but I have gone through all the available posts but could not figure out the best method in EF 6 version.

I have two tables

```
PersonPhone (PersonID, PhoneTypeID)

PhoneType(PhoneTypeID, Description)
```

PhoneTypes as just look ups (Cell, Office, Pager etc).  How do I generate equivalent Enums in code from PhoneType table.

Can anyone please provide steps to generate ENums from Look up tables?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is with a T4 Template that will automatically generate your Enum's from the table.

[Here is a great template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395000/t4-template-to-generate-enums) that I've used in a couple projects. Just change the connection string, and make sure the scripts assumptions about the format of your data are correct (i.e. that the id's are named `TableNameID`). Then add in the appropriate .tt files for each Enum, and run the template.

Comment: looks like I can't use it as enum any more.  I see my data has Guid instead of an auto-increment number in DB.  need to find another way as I can't create enum which expects int always :(

Comment: @techspider: Hi fellow dev. I'm the original author of the T4 script for lookup tables. In your case I would suggest to adjust the T$ script to generate static class with string/GUID properties and assign them your GUIDs. This would make it possible for you to use this class similar to Enum type, but with more flexibility about its values.

Comment: thanks @RobertKoritnik for your suggestion.  I'll try to check the route next time I come across